# Regex match string if not

Tags: javascript, html, regex, image, directory

I'm using regex to replace image source urls in an html file.

I want for example to replace `img/` with `<?= $folder ?>/img/`

The issue: 
When I run the regex multiple times it will replace `img/` again, creating:

```
<?= $folder ?>/<?= $folder ?>/img
```

..and so on. Is there a way to tell regex to replace `img/` if not already `<?= $folder ?>/img` ?

I am trying `/^(?:(?!<?= $folder ?>/img).)*$/` but not sure how to first match and check if that it doesn't already contain `<?= $folder ?>/img`

Comment: I don't know if it would be cleaner to look at, but you could first replace the full string with `[PLACEHOLDER]`, then do your replace, then replace `[PLACEHOLDER]` with your full string again. I believe you can do your replace with just a single RegEx, but this way would be an alternative that's a little more linear.

Comment: @anubhava i have updated my question

Comment: Why are you using regex for this? You only need to do a find and replace.

Comment: @Mikey it is for a gulp component which uses regex

Comment: Your regex `/^(?:(?!<?= $folder ?>\/img).)*$/` works fine and doesn't replace if same string is already there in input

Comment: Can you please add some examples of the image source urls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer regex, please try:

```js
function matchIfNot(str) {
  var newstr = str.replace(/^(?!(<\?=\s\$folder\s\?>\/))(img\/)/g, "<?= $folder ?>/img/")
  alert("Old string: " + str + "\nNew string: " + newstr)
}

matchIfNot("<?= $folder ?>/img/")
matchIfNot("img/")
```

Output:

```
Old string: <?= $folder ?>/img/
New string: <?= $folder ?>/img/

Old string: img/
New string: <?= $folder ?>/img/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `/(?!<\?= $folder \?>)img\//`.

The bit at the beginning there, the `(?!< ... )` is the notation for negative look-behind, that is, for checking if `...` is earlier in the string. In this case, we're checking if the string
`<\?= $folder \?>` (note the escaped question marks) is earlier in the string.
If that section is found earlier in a line with `img/`, it will be rejected, and won't match. So, each case of `img/` will only be matched once.

This regex will fail for lines with more than one occurence of `img/`. There might be a way to allow for multiple occurences, but it would likely be a very long regex; and in my opinion, usually when a regex gets too long, it might be time to switch to a different tool.

Comment: Please elaborate on how this regex answers the question.